# Setting custom target and action in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have a custom control that is reused frequently. It is meant to respond to a long press. I'd like to be able to set the target and selector in interface builder. Is there any method for having something like-

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet SEL longPressSelector;
```

Alternatively is there a way to add custom UIControlEvents that can be set it Interface Builder?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need to create an method with a return type of `IBAction`, and connect your button to that action.  When you drag the connection line it will give you an option of which control event you wish to call the method.

Comment: I know how to connect IBOutlets and IBActions. I want to know if you can create a new event that can be sent. Instead of responding to Touch Up Inside, it should respond to Long Press Up Inside, which is currently not an option.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  You always could manually create the button in code do your own detection of touch events.

Answer (score -3):

I think you can use

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

to start a NSTimer which will count time for you

and

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches  withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

to stop that timer and will get for how much time user tapped a view and then you can do an event according to that time for long press.

Hope, it'll help you.

Comment: UILongPressGestureRecognizers are preferrable to implementing those methods. I am more interested in sending events to a receiver.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, the OP asked if he can set the action to be executed from IB.